# Ask for a revision of freelancer's salary.

Tags: communication, salary, new-job, email

I work as a proofreader from home for a publishing house that emails me manuscripts to be proofread. The pay for every manuscript is based on the number of pages a manuscript has. There is an initial rate per page that's increased as the quality of proofreading improves, that's the rule of the company. Every proofread manuscript is then reviewed by my superior who then sends me a feedback of said proofread manuscripts. I have improved my quality of proofreading a lot and it shows in the last 3-4 manuscripts that I proofread. In the feedback of those 3-4 proofread manuscripts, my superior has mentioned that I have done a great job proofreading those manuscripts and have not made many errors. After that, I have received more manuscripts but my rate has not been increased. Do I request my superior to revise my rate per page or do I wait for them to take a step on their own? If I should request for a revision then how should I phrase it? This is my first job so I am a bit green, I started working for this company only 6 months ago. Any help is fully appreciated.

Comment: Do you have this promise of more pay for better work in writing somewhere?  Was this just something said verbally during the interview process?

Comment: If your employer is not aware you are unhappy with your current rate, they might not have a reason to increase it, outside of the conditions they have already defined to warrant an increase.  Experienced freelancers are able to charge (and demand) more for their services.  Of course the (demand) part of that statement comes at a risk.

Comment: @raterus It's stated in their Rules and Procedure document.

Comment: @Ramhound they increased my pay rate before when I showed a fair bit of improvement so why would they not do so now after I have improved by leaps and bounds

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with companies, if you desire to be paid more, you have to take that first step and have that conversation.  The good news in your case is that you have something in writing.  Take the Rules & Procedures document highlighting the section about increased pay to your boss, and simply ask for an honest evaluation and what more you need to do in order to qualify for an increase.